# Вопрос по объектам java

Tags: java, ооп

Изучаю java. Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что тяжело связывать объекты при решении определенных задача. Есть задачи более понятные, там получается, но бывает совершенно непонятно.

Пример: "Написать виртуальную файловую систему с функциями добавления, удаления и т.д."
Смотрел некоторые решения в инете, у многих разные, конкретно для меня пытаюсь разбивать в уме задачу на подзадачи, но, видно, не совсем правильно умею это делать, тяжело объяснить, но в данном примере не понимаю, как клеить пути к файлам и папкам, как это хранить (не в смысле как хранить, в коллекции, например, а в смысле, что как при обходе каталог сделать, чтобы правильно отобразился путь, то есть связь объектов папки и файла).

Ну, представление есть  - класс FileSystem  с наследниками FileDir и File, ну и т.д., хранить в коллекции. Но когда начинаю писать уже код, то постоянно сталкиваюсь с тем, что что-то непонятно, и не могу продвинутся. Чаще всего, это когда есть связь с 2-3 объектами, либо как-то передается через 1 объект в другой, ну, сложновато так объяснить, надеюсь, получилось.

Посоветуйте книги, может, есть в каких-то книгах разбор, как нужно строить объекты, алгоритмы, шаблоны, типичные подходы для решения задач. Или, может, есть какие-то методики, которые можно применить для упрощения построения объектов и связи между ними?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: >Ну представление есть - класс FileSystem с наследниками FileDir и File

Не не надо наследовать директорию от файловой системы.

Если у вас ООП это совсем не значит что обязательно нужно всё от всего наследовать. Прочитайте любую статью про парадигму ООП.

Comment: Очень правильное замечание. Наследование - это отношение "is a" ("является"). Каждый раз, перед тем как унаследовать класс A от класса B, спрашивайте себя: является ли класс B классом A? Если ответ отрицательный, то наследование неприменимо и нужен другой вид отношений, например, аггрегация ("содержит") или композиция ("состоит из").

Comment: Это понятно, у меня проблема не с наследованием, а с более мелкими связями объектов. Например, как (механизм) хранения путей для виртуальной системы (как передавать и что связывающим объектам). 

Да и насчет наследования от файловой системы, просто видел пример в инете, на довольно авторитетном ресурсе, и там писали, что решение нормальное:)

Comment: >>писали, что решение нормальное

Так мы с вами на пальцах говорим.

Если вам древовидную структуру хранить надо, так прочитайте про хранение дерева.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почитайте про шаблоны проектирования (design patterns). Доступным языком о них рассказывается в книге [Head First Design Patterns](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/6108824/), более подробно - в [GOF](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/2457392/). В вашем конкретном случае подошёл бы паттерн "[Компоновщик](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA_%28%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%29)".

Comment: Спасибо. Буду смотреть.